# If I found the Quest home level, but haven't spoken to the leader, does the Quest Artifact count as "generated" when wishing for artifacts?

Tags: nethack

I've been on the Quest home level, but haven't ventured more than a few steps. I have Magicbane and Vorpal Blade, and have seen no other artifacts in my travels. I'm hoping to add 2 more artifacts with my remaining wishes before going on the quest. Looking at the wiki, I see my chances are better for getting them beforehand. But, since the Quest artifact is guaranteed, I'm wondering if it's pre-counted as generated.  The odds change significantly if it is, and I might be better served only trying for one more. So, any info would help.

Answer (score 2):

The quest artifact is initially in the possession of your quest *nemesis*, not your quest leader.

Unless you've visited the bottom level of the quest, your quest artifact won't count as generated yet.